# Cant Add A Caption To My Popup (html, js, css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, caption

I'm trying to add a caption to my image popup, so that the text appears after I click the image but is not displayed before then.

Below is the current code that I have in place and the way I tried to add the popup caption. Any help or suggestions would be amazing and greatly appreciated.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal1");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg1");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img02");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(236, 12, 12);
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" class="tester" style="height: 185px; width: 175px;" src="image/offwhiteuncjordan.png" />
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to get the image with this **var img = document.getElementById("myImg1");** but is not the right image ID, please fix that by editing your question, same for the modal ID.

Comment: Besides what is commented above, `document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1]` will be undefined, since you have only a single element with class `close`, so you need `[0]` instead of `[1]`

Comment: if you fix what we said above and add an `alt` to the `img`, it will work